# Unable to send media to Twilio Whatsapp sandbox

Tags: twilio

I am trying to send a media file from my glitch app to Twilio Whatsapp Sandbox but am only receiving the body message and not the media. It shows up on the Twilio dashboard as delivered with the correct media.

I am trying to send a message with a mediaUrl attached but I am not receiving it on my Twilio Whatsapp sandbox number. Here's my code:

```
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages
       .create({
           to: request.body.From,
           from: request.body.To,
           body: "Bruce Lee",
           mediaUrl: "https://i.imgur.com/a4yPMo4.mp4",
       })
      .then(message => {
          console.log(message.sid);
        })
        .done();
```

In my twilio dashboard it says delivered but I only receive the body and not the media. Here's a snapshot.

https://i.ibb.co/wBkrhVh/stacktwilio.png

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Twilio documentation on sending media over WhatsApp](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api#sending-a-freeform-whatsapp-message-with-media-attachment) says that supported media includes images (JPEG, JPG, PNG) and audio files and PDF, with a maximum size of 5MB.

It looks like you're trying to send a video file, which is currently unsupported.

Comment: Hi, I did try with quite a few image formats including the ones mentioned above but in vain. Those messages were always 'Queued' on the Twilio dashboard and I could see the media icon besides it, but the media file wasn't present inside the message log. I even checked the mime types and the files did comply with them. They were well below the file size limit. Is it something to do with sandbox?

Comment: Being able to send media is very, very new (I literally found out we could do it because of your question). I managed to send myself pictures earlier today, so it appears to be working now. I would try again now with a JPG or PNG (definitely not an mp4) and see what happens.

Comment: Thank You. It has started working through no changes of mine. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: Good news! Like I said, media support is very new, so looks like things are changing fast. WhatsApp support is still beta, so things may change underneath you.

Comment: @philnash Any way to refer to a local image file in server using PHP for the mediaURL? Examples only show https hosted image url.

Comment: @FreeKrishna No, the image must be available online somewhere. If you are developing locally you can use a tunnelling service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) to expose your local server.

Comment: @FreeKrishna No, the image must be available online somewhere. If you are developing locally you can use a tunnelling service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) to expose your local server.